# Use module function instead of Base function Julia

Tags: julia

Lets say I have a Julia module, `MyModule`, that defines a function called `conv()` for 1D convolution. I would like to be able to call this function via `MyModule.conv()` in a file that imports or uses the file. Example:

```
import MyModule.conv
MyModule.conv()
```

However, I cannot get this syntax to work; Julia still calls `Base.conv()` instead of `MyModule.conv()`. I have tried all the different styles of `using` and `import` but cannot get this syntax to work.

Is this functionality available in Julia? I feel like I have seen this be implemented in other Julia packages but cannot find an example that works.

**EDIT**

Current setup is as follows; there is no reference to conv() anywhere in ModA outside of the definition.

```
module ModA

function conv(a, b)
    println("ModA.conv")
end

end
```

Then, in another file,

```
import ModA
conv(x, y) #still calls Base.conv()
```

**SOLVED**
This was entirely my fault. The import wasn't working because of an incorrect LOAD_PATH calling a different version of the file than I thought was being called (finding the first one in the LOAD_PATH, which was not the one that I was editing). Entirely my fault...

Comment: Write your module as you have in the edit. Then in another file (or at the REPL), type `using ModA`, then `ModA.conv(randn(2), randn(2))`. Is that not the behaviour you are after?

Comment: in ModA, you should `import Base.conv`.

Comment: If you `import Base.conv` in `ModA` then you will be overloading methods onto it, and there will be only one `conv` function at play. As I understand it, the intent here was to keep two separate functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
module ModA
   conv() = println("Calling ModA.conv")
end

module ModB  # Import just conv from ModA
   using ..ModA.conv # Could have used import ..ModA.conv instead
   conv()            # if we want to be able to extend ModA.conv
end

module ModC  # Import ModA and use qualified access to access ModA.conv
   import ..ModA
   ModA.conv()
end
```

You must make sure not to make any reference to `conv` inside `ModA` before you have defined your own function, or it will already have looked up `Base.conv` and associated the name `conv` with that.

Comment: This is the functionality that I am trying to achieve, however it does not work as intended. It still calls `Base.conv()`, even though as far as I can tell, it really should not. Any further suggestions about what might be causing it to keep calling `Base.conv()`?

Comment: Did you try my example code above? Doesn't it work for you? It works perfectly for me (on Julia 0.4). Please notice that there is two combinations that work. If you `import ModA` then you have to use a qualified access (as in`ModC`).

Comment: Your example code works exactly as intended, and how I have used Julia in the past. I just solved my issue; it wasn't working because of an incorrect LOAD_PATH calling a different version of the file than I thought was being called (finding the first one in the LOAD_PATH, which was not the one that I was editing). Thank you for your help!